# How to run java program (jar file) via vbscript?

Tags: java, windows, vbscript

I have this script:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
dim a
a = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram\MyApplication.jar"
WshShell.Run "javaw -jar " & a
```

but when I execute, I got error message: "Error: Unable to access jarfile: C:\Program"

the problem is... my program path contain space(s).
How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this? This worked for me.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
dim a
a = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram\MyApplication.jar"
WshShell.Run "java -jar " &  chr(34) & a & chr(34)
```

Answer (score 1):

put your path in double "" see if it works. So your script should look like ""path with spaces""

Comment: it give another error: run.vbs(3,7) Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected end of statement