# How to capture event in a browser (IE) and trigger a local java application?

Tags: java, html

When I browse an external website (so I can't make changes to the web application) and do a form submit (by clicking a button on webpage), I want a local Java application to be triggered.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: are you looking for browser plugins/add-ons/extensions???

Comment: @AbishekManoharan i have browser restriction so cannot add add-on/plugin.

Comment: When you click a html button you want to start a java program?

Comment: You can use a vb script to start a java application right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29003918/how-to-run-java-program-jar-file-via-vbscript/29005297#29005297

Comment: @Pasupathi Ok. vb script can trigger a java app. Agreed. But how the vb script is going to be triggered at the click of a button on the webpage (it is an external website - so I can't make changes to the web application/webpage).

Comment: On clicking external website you need to open a java app.? Maybe try some web drivers, or selenium script to achieve what you're looking for..