# Running Jar File via VBScript

Tags: java, vbscript, jar

I have a jar file that I would like to run using VBScript. But I don't want to leave the command prompt open while the application is running.

Currently, I can achieve this by putting the java command in a BAT file as follows:

```
java -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -jar myApp.jar
```

I then have a VBScript that would call the BAT file as follows:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "myApp.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

But I think that using a VBScript to call a BAT file to invoke the java command is unnecessary. To optimize, I wanted the VBScript to invoke the java command directly so that I can disregard the BAT file.

I tried replacing the VBScript into something like the following:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "java -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -jar myApp.jar" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

But the following error occurs:

```
Error: The system cannot find the file specified.
Code: 80070002
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `WshShell.Run "cmd /c java -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -jar myApp.jar"`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run java program (jar file) via vbscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29003918)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBscript - "The system cannot find the file specified"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33389849)

Comment: @Lankymart Yup, saw these posts when I was searching. The first one does not work on me. The second 1 somewhat works but the command prompt is still visible.

Comment: You should remove those `chr(34)` before and after your command

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Removing the chr(34) works. But the command prompt shows while the app is running. I wanted the command prompt not to be displayed while the app is running.

Comment: Then use javaw instead of java.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Literally didn't know about javaw. Thanks man! This now works!

Answer (score -1):

Change "java" to absolute path such as "C:\Program Files\jdkXXX\bin\java.exe"

Comment: Since this will be used by several users, is there anyway that the script to search the actual location of the java.exe?